# Update a column based on its value

Tags: mysql

To update a table we use this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET column = value WHERE column = value
```

Is there any way to update a column by its value? For example:

Table 'test' has 2 columns called 'one' and 'two'.

I'll set them: 'one' to 10, and 'two' to 20, and i wish to update the columm that have value 10, this is variable, and i can't know wich exactly column it is.

Thanks

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes indicative of poor design, i.e. a lack of normalization

Answer (score 0):

You'd have the query the table first:

`select * from myTable where col1 = 10 or col2 = 10`

Then, you'll need server-side code (like php, ruby, python, etc) to determine which column has the needed value, and you can build a new update query based on that:

`update myTable set col1 = 20`

However, I can't think of a scenario where this is an efficient way of managing the data. You may want to reconsider how the database is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `IF` syntax. Perhaps it can be used in an assignment inside an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 UPDATEs, one for each column.

```
UPDATE test SET one = ... WHERE one = 10;
UPDATE test SET two = ... WHERE two = 10;
```